# Is it possible to mix template-derived C++ classes with Qt's Q_OBJECT?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qobject

In my application, I have the following class hierarchy:

```
class Word
{
    ...
}

template <typename T> class Dictionary
{
    ...
};

class WordDictionary : public Dictionary<Word>
{
    Q_OBJECT

    ...
}
```

The WordDictionary class parses a dictionary which takes a long time. I am running the parsing function from within a separate thread and I want it to be able to signal the GUI thread from time to time to provide progress updates based on the current line number being parsed. That's why I want it to be a Q_OBJECT. I tried to make the base class Dictionary a Q_OBJECT but got a message that Q_OBJECT templates are not supported. When I removed the macro, leaving only WordDictionary as Q_OBJECT, I get a bunch of error messages of the general form:

> .\GeneratedFiles\Release\moc_dictionary.cpp(44) : error C2039: 'staticMetaObject' : is not a member of 'Dictionary'
>          with
>          [
>              T=Word
>          ]

Is there anything I can do to make my template-derived WordDictionary class a Q_OBJECT other than hardcoding the template functions inside it, producing a lot of boilerplate code?

**edit:** Changing the template declaration to:

```
template <typename T> class Dictionary : public QObject
```

made the code compile. I'm not sure if I'm not doing something stupid and if this will work correctly, though.

Comment: [Why Doesn't Qt Use Templates for Signals and Slots](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/templates.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do this directly  but there are usable work-rounds.  See the article [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq15-academic.html).

> While it is theoretically possible for
>   moc to handle templates, it would be
>   extremely complex to implement, and
>   would be highly impractical to use:
>   For each template instantiation, moc
>   would have to generate the appropriate
>   meta-object code, and the generated
>   code would have to be included once
>   per link unit---which becomes a
>   nightmare to maintain once a template
>   class is used with the same template
>   parameter in different compilation
>   units.
>
> If the signals and slots don't require
>   the template parameter to be part of
>   the prototype, the workaround is to
>   make a template class inherit a
>   QObject subclass that provides the
>   required signals and slots.  If
>   signals and slots need to use the
>   template parameters, the Observer
>   pattern is an alternative.