# QT_TR_NOOP and template class

Tags: c++, qt, templates

QT_TR_NOOP should mark my string for translation, i.e extract it in linguist. If I use in regulat class it works as expected, however if I used it in template class specialization it doesn't mark my string for translation. I do the following :

```
enum TESTEnum
{
   TestItem
};

EnumMeta<TESTEnum>::EnumMeta()
{
  mEnumStrs.push_back(
    std::pair<int,std::string>(
    TestItem,
    QT_TR_NOOP("TestItem")));
}
```

EDIT: Since the class doesnot have to inherit from QObject, for the QT_TR_NOOP macro to work I think the question is not duplicate. As far as I understand, the class needs to inherit from QObject only if I need to have signal/slots in the class or using qt property system,and that is not possible for class templates.In my case I just want to extract the strings for translation, and QT_TR_NOOP works for non template class that doesnot inherit from QObject, but it doesnot work with template class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mix template-derived C++ classes with Qt's Q\_OBJECT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238204/is-it-possible-to-mix-template-derived-c-classes-with-qts-q-object)

Comment: @Hcorg This is nothing to do with the `moc`, `QT_TR_NOOP` is a marker for `lupdate`.

Comment: @cmannett85 moc and lupdate probably use same C++ parser. Also - if something can't be processed by moc it will not have proper translations available for lupdate to use

Comment: @Hcorg "if something can't be processed by moc it will not have proper translations available for lupdate to use" Why do you say that?  `lupdate` uses the files specified in the `.pro` file - it has nothing to do with the `moc`.

Comment: @cmannett85 QT_TR_NOOP requires 'current class' to be Q_OBJECT. Q_OBJECT classes are processed by moc, including some code generation for proper `tr` work (I think, maybe tr works fine without moc). Still - underlying C++ parser restrictions might be the same

Comment: @Hcorg "QT_TR_NOOP requires 'current class' to be Q_OBJECT" How do you know that?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_TR_NOOP

Comment: Actually I am using QT_TR_NOOP with nontemplate class that doesnot inherit from QObject, and it extracts the strings for translation in that class. It doesnot extract when I use it with template class, I guess it is because it can't guess the context for translation from the template class. When I use QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP and give the context explicitly it works with the template class too, but is some inconvenient

Comment: @Hcorg in the link you provided it doesnot say that the class should inherit from QObject.